# start ndk SanAngeles from shell@android

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-activity

I have put the SanAngeles demo to run in my phone.

Here are steps I took:

```
$ android update project -p . --target android-14
$ ndk-build -B V=1 APP_OPTIM=debug NDK_DEBUG=1
$ ant debug install
```

It install fine. I saw the program was installed from the list of Apps in my smartphone. If I click on the icon DemoActivity, it runs.

But if I try to do it on host console:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android: $ am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.sanangeles/com.example.sanangeles.demoactivity

Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.sanangeles/com.example.sanangeles.demoactivity}
does not exist.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `ndk-build clean` is usually equivalent to remove all the compiled libraries, are you sure that this are the real commands that you have used?

Comment: Hi... I tried again, this time without the clean. The same thing happened.

Comment: no, wait, what are the steps? you are missing the building phase here, you still have to build your libraries after a clean, you have to do `ndk-build`. Describe your steps.

Comment: Hi. Just updated the steps.. in the beginning without clean.

Comment: Just solved it: $ am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.sanangeles/com.example.sanangeles.DemoActivity . Just the DemoActivity has to be in capital letters.